# Python: Sorting a list of classes

Tags: python

I have a list called columnVariable. This list contains a bunch of instances of a class. Each class has a property sequenceNumber

when I run the following command:

```
for obj in columnVariable:
 print obj.sequenceNumber
```

I get the following output

```
3 
1
2
10
11
```

I'd like to sort the list by the property sequenceNumber. The output I like is:

```
1 
2
3
10
11
```

When I try the following:

```
for obj in columnVariable:
 print sorted(obj.sequenceNumber)
```

I get the output

```
[u'3']
[u'1']
[u'2']
[u'0', u'1']
[u'1', u'1']
```

It looks like each individual sequence number is being sorted instead of sorting the items in the list based on the sequence number.

I'm newer to python and so a little help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `print sorted(columnVariable, key = lambda x: x.sequenceNumber)`

Comment: hint: `key=lambda x: int(x.sequenceNumber)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use sorted with a `key` argument. eg.

```
from operator import attrgetter

for obj in sorted(columnVariable, key=attrgetter('sequenceNumber')):
    print(obj)
```

Edit:

Since you want to sort strings numerically, it's more appropriate to use a lambda function here

```
for obj in sorted(columnVariable, key=lambda x: int(x.sequenceNumber)):
    print(obj)
```

Some people struggle to understand `lambda` functions, so I'll mention that it's ok to write a normal function definition for your key function

```
def int_sequence_number_key(obj):
    return int(obj.sequenceNumber)

for obj in sorted(columnVariable, key=int_sequence_number_key):
    print(obj)
```

Now it's also possible to write tests for `int_sequence_number_key` which is important for covering corner cases (eg what happens if you can have `None` or some other objects that can't be converted to `int`)

Comment: `sequenceNumber` isn't a list, it is a stringified integer.

Comment: Nice. What if `sequenceNumber` is a string? (It looks like that may be the case.)

Comment: @ppperry, in that case, this answer (using attrgetter) probably isn't what you want. You should use a lambda, but include int. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: @ppperry: This answer doesn't depend on it being a list.  Really, though, an attribute called `sequenceNumber` Ought to stored as an `int`.

Comment: sequenceNumber is actually a string. I modified print(obj) to print (obj.seqenenceNumber) otherwise I just got the location as obj is a list.

I'm one of those people that struggle to understand lamba functions (as I haven't really used them yet) so thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 4):

you may want to try this:

```
print sorted(columnVariable, key = lambda x: int(x.sequenceNumber))
```

Comment: woah. word for word (y)

Answer (score 0):

The python `sorted` function takes a `key` function as an argument, which can be used to specify how to sort. In this case, you would use `sorted(columnVariable, key=lambda x:x.sequenceNumber)`.

The above code can be made faster by using the operator module:

```
from operator import attrgetter
sorted(columnVariable, key=attergetter("sequenceNumber")).
```